# How to merge geographically similar polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing

I'm working with zoning data at the parcel level for a city, e.g., each parcel has a zoning attribute. My goal is to create a contiguous zoning map without intersections from roads and highways. I manually edited a portion of the city to show my intended result.

Here is a portion of my initial map:

[image]

And here is a rough manual edit of how I'd like to dissolve the features and remove the gaps where the roads are:

[image]

Is there any geoprocessing that can achieve this result without manually editing the features to be contiguous?

Comment: How are you defining the rules here?  It looks like the green space in the middle is growing to meet the surrounding land uses. Why don't they grow to meet the open space?

Comment: Related (and possibly duplicate of one): http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137060/ or http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142253/ or http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93515/ And there's another one around here I can't find right now, but I think it was looking to fill in gaps with all one attribute. Do you have a street centerline layer? Your main problem now is getting the zones to meet in the middle of streets (which dissolve and aggregate cannot solve). With centerlines Jason's answer at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98469/ might help, or you could split street polys.

Comment: What license level do you have and are centerlines available? I can think of a few workflows to do this, but they all require a higher license level (Advanced ideally) and having street centerlines available.

Comment: I have an advanced license and do have street centerlines available.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions.

1. Make one large polygon the overlays everything and the use the
   *Erase* function (info license only) to get the gaps as polygons. Now break up this polygon into a fishnet and use spatial joins. Now *Dissolve* on the value that gives you the colors above.
2. Use *Spatial Allocation* to fill the empty space. Polygonize it, do not simplify. Now *Dissolve* on the value that gives you the colors above.

Some [instructions](http://www.wwu.edu/huxley/spatial/tut/erase.htm) for using erase without the info license.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Aggregate Polygons (Cartography)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00700000000s000000) tool in ArcGIS. Looks like it is what are you looking for:

[image]

Comment: Note this tool requires an Advanced level license.